# Embedding A Website Within Another

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, forum

I am currently writing a website in nothing more than HTML and CSS for a client. This client had very few needs, just a few pages to display info, and they wanted to be able to edit the website easily themselves, so I immediately think "Weebly!" Well, this turns out to be a bad idea, as my client is now requesting a forum directly on their site. I don't have access to ASP.NET, which I would normally use in this situation, nor can I use PHP or anything of that nature, and of course my Silverlight is taken away (as that runs user-side). So, my first thought was to set up a Conforums (www.conforums.com) forum and put it in my client's site via an Iframe. This turns out not to work out so well as the user is logged out every time they click on a link in the forum (from the Iframe). So, my question is, without using modern-age methods such as PHP, ASP.NET or the like (straight-up HTML, CSS, Javascript), how can I embed my Conforums forum (or, for that matter, any external website) on my client's site without their users being logged out every time they click a link on the forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all due respect, I don't ever recommend this approach. It's largely frowned upon as it consumes bandwidth traffic that someone else is paying for. If the forum is absolutely necessary I would simply link to it.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. I remember every time I used to go to a site that linked to their forum and thought "wouldn't it be nice if the forum could be within the site itself?," but now I'm starting to feel more sympathetic to those that designed those sites. I'm thinking I might just have to go that way myself.

Answer (score 1):

Going to be tough. Fetching resources (and in this case, an entire site) from an origin other than your own domain isn't really a thing people get to do. You're definitely not going to save cookies or session variables that way. The iFrame thing might be the best thing for your situation.

But help is coming sort of: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Talki - http://tal.ki? Talki is a forum you can embed via Javascript.

What about a hosted forum solution? http://www.forum-software.org/forum-reviews/hosted?sort=alphabetical Lists some options.

Comment: Actually, Talki would have worked perfectly, but my client needs more control over the forum than Talki can offer, but I have some other projects I can fir Talki right into! Thanks for showing me this!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty late But there is a way, which includes CYMA"S answer and adding Weebly
The trick is to make a whole entire page
Go to Theme>
Edit or so
In there it brings up a code editor
Mess around with it and make a New HTML file
Copy in that TK script and you're golden
Just make a new page and select the new html you made

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. I mean how does .tk (tiki) do it?
Looking at .tk page source I can see:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name="description" content="example">
    <meta name="keywords" content="example">
  </head>
  <frameset rows="*" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="NO">

    <frame src="http://example.com " name="frame_content" scrolling="auto" noresize>
  </frameset>
  <noframes>
    <body>
    </body>
  </noframes>
</html>
```

It had some JavaScript which I cut out, but I don't think it was necessary for this.

Comment: Actually, that works pretty awesomely, if only I had access to my <head> tags. Using something like Weebly, I don't. But this would have been my answer. Trust me, never using Weebly again.